# When did 'venereal disease' become STI?

Tags: language-evolution, historical-change

Why is it that the term *venereal disease* has been dropped in favour of *sexually transmitted infection*, or 'STI' for short? The change seemed to date from the advent of AIDS.

Was it that the word 'venereal' was associated uniquely with heterosexual relationships?

Comment: I think the current en vogue initialism is STI (Sexually Transmitted Infection).

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think hepatitis B was ever classed as a venereal disease.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you are right, but it is, I believe classed as an STI. I wonder why?

Comment: When did *social disease* become *venereal disease*?

Comment: Well now we can honestly answer that we don't have a venereal disease.

Comment: I was curious when they stopped being STDs (diseases) and became STIs (infections).  Or is that a British vs Americanism.

Comment: @Edwin Hep B *is* frequently considered an STD. Like HIV, the modes of transmission are either blood to blood contact, sexual contact, and vertical transmission (mother to child). Hep C is similar.

Comment: @DavidM No, I have the sense that it started as STD here and then went to STI, perhaps to get away from the dreaded idea of 'disease'.

Comment: @WS2 it seems to be more related to the chronic asymptomatic states that are still infectious …

Comment: I think that HIV / STI are more euphemistic than VD. Saying that a person with Hep B (... Other risk factors for developing HBV infection include working in a healthcare setting, transfusions, dialysis, acupuncture, tattooing, sharing razors or toothbrushes with an infected person, travel in countries where it is endemic, and residence in an institution: Wikipedia) has VD seems to be adding insult to injury.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth speaking as a physician Hep B is frequently spread via exposure to infectious body fluid (commonly sexually transmitted).  The other risk factors you've mentioned are contributory due to the exposure to said fluids. (BTW - HIV has most of the same risks).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per  [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexually_transmitted_disease):  the nomenclature changed in the 1990s to STD. It has only been in the last few years that STI had come on the scene.  (I'm a physician and I still routinely see and say STD.)

I think the AIDS epidemic made a lot of headway in causing the change to STD. First, because of the uptick in homosexual spread -- the original (unfortunate) name for AIDS was GRID:  Gay Related Immunodeficiency.   (Venereal wouldn't be as appropriate for men.)  And, second to emphasize the sexual spread of the disease *without euphemism.*

Prior to AIDS, VD was a dirty secret never addressed in polite society. It was something that "only soldiers, sailors, and prostitutes could get."  It was this sort of thinking that promulgated the rapid spread of HIV through the world.

While STDs and more broadly STIs (seemingly preferred because of the asymptomatic nature of certain types of chronic STDs) are more openly discussed than in prior decades, education is still lacking on proper prevention.  Many diseases are making comebacks:  gonorrhea is starting to show signs of multiple antibiotic resistance, for example.

Comment: Why is this true: "Venereal wouldn't be as appropriate for men"

Comment: @duckmayr In that it refers to *of Venus*.  Certainly, it was used in the sense that Venus being the goddess of love and sex.  But, there's even an inherent blaming of the woman in this, too.  Without going off on a complete tangent, the notion is that women drove men to sexual desire through their channeling of Venus.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for that explainer!

Answer (score 4):

A Google Ngram shows a [rise in *sexually transmitted disease* over *venereal disease*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=venereal%20disease,sexually%20transmitted%20disease,sexually%20transmitted%20infection&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,venereal%20disease;,c0;.t1;,sexually%20transmitted%20disease;,c0;.t1;,sexually%20transmitted%20infection;,c0) starting in the mid-1970s, starting in medical and public health circles and gradually becoming mainstream by the 1990s. *Venereal disease* remains the most common term in print, but it may be displaced before too long.

Historically, gonorrhea and syphilis were the most prevalent, and considered the only diseases transmitted through sexual contact. The 1873 *[Smith's Family Physician](https://archive.org/details/smithsfamilyphys00smituoft)* flatly defines venereal disease as these two and none other. But by the 1970s, other conditions and infections such as HPV, genital herpes, and hepatitis C were growing in concern. A 1981 paper in *The American Journal of Nursing* entitled "[VD to STD: Redefining Venereal Disease](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3462865)," did not invent the term *STD*, but did declare *venereal disease* obsolete, as it was too restrictive.

Some of these were conditions were not only not traditional venereal diseases, but they could also be spread by non-sexual mechanisms. Some, [such as HIV/AIDS](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1989-05-19/news/8902020449_1_silent-epidemic-transmitted-venereal-diseases) required different public health approaches. *Venereal* could also be seen as a needless euphemism, with *sexually transmitted disease* being more clinical. So in the U.S., not only did middle school health class change its jargon, but [names of some government offices](http://www.mass.gov/eohhs/gov/departments/dph/programs/id/std/) and [terminology of some public health laws](http://atg.wa.gov/AGOOpinions/opinion.aspx?section=archive&id=8722#.Uz8FvvldWyU) adopted the new terminology in the mid- to late 1980s. (*VD* [does persist](http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/3313.60).)

[The UN notes](http://unterm.un.org/dgaacs/unterm.nsf/8fa942046ff7601c85256983007ca4d8/522b7f3a1f502989852569fa0000ba92?OpenDocument) that

> STD and STI may be thought of as modern terms for "venereal disease" (VD), a term initially used to refer to syphilis and gonorrhoea, which were once thought to be a single disease. The term "venereal" emphasizes the part played by sex in the spread of diseases that would not otherwise be considered as a single group. …
>
> N.B. Although one might think that there are two distinct terms here -- STI for infections and STD for diseases -- the two seem to be used interchangeably, and without particular attention being paid to whether the focus is on infection or disease.

The World Health Organization's International Classification of Diseases 10th revision (ICD10), adopted in 1994, reflects the shift. What in ICD9 was *Syphilis And Other Venereal Diseases* has been redesignated in ICD10 as *Infections with a predominantly sexual mode of transmission* (though it explicitly excludes HIV and some other conditions).

But as noted, *venereal disease* is arguably the most widely understood term, especially among older generations.My generation was taught in health class (early 1990s California) to say *sexually transmitted disease*, but we still understood the [*Friends* episode](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/The_One_Where_Underdog_Gets_Away) how *VD* was a bad thing to be associated with.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](http://www.thestdproject.com/std-vs-sti-whats-the-difference/) is probably correct one. I was going to elaborate on how VDs and STDs are not really just diseases, but couldn't phrase it right. The main culprit is the D word. Disease.

EDIT: I missed the second half of the question. For this, I apologize. AIDS certainly did assist in the propagation of STI because a person could be HIV positive, meaning they are infected, but not suffering from AIDS, the disease.

Comment: That answers STD vs STI not venereal disease.

Comment: @DavidM _While the term STD has been around a long time (way back when, it was called venereal disease – named after Venus, the goddess of love), STI is becoming increasingly popular._ So it went from VD -> STD -> STI. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: @Tucker: Still, this does not answer WHY it went from VD->STD. Yes, it did. And we have the reason for STD->STI. But we still have no reason for VD->STD.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Because venereal implied only women could get it. Men were also susceptible, so it became STD.

Comment: @Tucker I find that difficult to believe. I well remember the 1960s, long before AIDS and HIV came on the scene. It was well-known that both men and women got VD.

Comment: @WS2 True, but prior to the 1960s there wasn't a feminist movement. I think that I may have phrased it wrong, so allow me to attempt it once more. Despite both men and woman able to contract VDs, they were assumed to be the fault of the female. This is because most VDs were transmitted via prostitutes and males usually got them from there, thus the feminine connotation. This is evident with the attitudes of the times in some WWII propaganda posters, church newsletters, outraged puritans writing to their congressman, etc. After the 1960s movement it changed. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Tucker I suppose so. Something like this?http://flavorwire.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/vintage_std_poster.jpg or this https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYMhaYfLhEvhOYZsBrRBmKJu6adbFJthEy0wJ5MpIKRRYcvjpOlm0D4A

Comment: @WS2 Yes, something like that. I am trying to find where the term VD originated and how old it goes. Suggested by its origin in the form of a Latin name (Venus, goddess of all good things), I am going to place it in the early to mid 1700s. Therefore I am looking for old medical manuscripts from that period to see what they would have called it. In the meantime, there is [this resource](http://www.faqs.org/childhood/Th-W/Venereal-Disease.html) that may shed some light on this topic.

Comment: @WS2 I've [found something quite interesting](http://imgur.com/KPwJQPY) ([Source](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1054037/)). Of course it isn't _definite_ proof of the origins, but it helps guide from where the form of the word could have come from -- although I might be a century late from my previous estimates (17th century as oppose to 1700s). I still need to hunt for a more definitive answer, but at least we know we're looking in the right places.

Comment: @Tucker I didn't read it all but caught an amazing statistic that 65 million Americans have an STI of some sort. I knew that HIV/AIDS was vastly higher in America than in most European countries but had no idea those were the kinds of statistics. I would think some of those STIs thay mention are relatively harmless.

Comment: @Tucker I think it proceeded in the form of epidemics in the early Modern period. There was an 'epidemic' in London in the 16th century I seem to have read.

Comment: @WS2 I think you're right. I think we need to go further back than the 1600s and dip our toes into the 1500s to find the source of this, but it was nice to find a reference to the term dating back to the these period. I will see if I can find something. So, to recap, the advent of the acronym STI came about in the 1990s after AIDS and HIV and people were found to have the ability to have an infection without having a disease. STD was the standard prior to this changed during the 1960s to be more gender neutral. All that's left is to find out where VD came from and we'll have our answer!

Comment: @WS2 I have to admit, I'm dumb. After scouring through the sources of the Internet, a simple glance at [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/venereal) states that this word "_Originated 1400–50 from late Middle English venereal, from Latin venereus (“of sexual love”), from Venus (“goddess of love”)._" So, we have to go to that period and see if there is evidence of the word becoming commonplace through some means (perhaps a standard introduced by one of the great universities of the time).

Comment: @Tucker The first reference to *venereal* in the OED is dated 1475; and to *venereal disease*, 1658. 'Venereal disease is vulgarly called the French Pox'. The latter is interesting since in the sixties we used to call it 'the pox', and for all I know gonorrhea is still called that today.

Comment: @WS2 Wow! Hey, that's great! I didn't think to check the Oxford Dictionary. I guess that should have been the first place to look. Sadly I was not alive during the 1960s. I wasn't even a twinkle in the father's eyes. A personal observation is always a good thing because we know the essence of the times.

Comment: @Tucker I am, of course, talking of Britain. I don't know if Americans called it 'the Pox'. You do realise, don't you, that the OED is not the same thing as 'Oxford Dictionaries'. The latter are just normal dictionaries, albeit very good ones. The 'Oxford English Dictionary' is the authoritative guide to the history of English. It is avaialable on line but they charge a subscription. (The hard version runs to over 30 volumes) Many people (me included) in the UK have on-line access through their municipal libraries, who mostly maintain subscriptions on behalf of their local taxpayers.

Comment: @WS2 I'm unsure about whether or not it was used in the USA during those times, but I'll see if I can find some news clippings or references to it from novels written in that period or about that period. As for the OED, I had realized that it was the Oxford English Dictionary, and not 'Oxford Dictionaries', and I do have a fairly old version in my possession, and sadly rarely used. It is no wonder then that I couldn't use this as a reference as I am not a subscriber to the OED. There is a British Library near where I live, perhaps I can go there and see. Doubt it will, but worth a shufti.

Comment: @Tucker Do you mean you have an old version of the OED? You mean all 30 something volumes? I have never before known a private individual to have one. I've only ever seen them in libraries! Do you know of the book 'The Surgeon of Crowthorne' about the inmate of a top security hospital for the criminally insane who was responsible for creating the first version of the OED? I actually live in the village of Crowthorne!